# Finding Submodules of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules, extension-field, quotient-spaces

I am trying to find all the submodules of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and then using that to determine if it is indecomposable. Is it correct to use the factors of $x^3$: $1,x,x^2$, to create submodules using these elements, or pairs of them such that the sum of all the degrees is less than three, like $(x), (1,x), (x^2,x)$ for example. Is this approach correct or is it not guaranteed that all of them will indeed be submodules? Furthermore, to determine if it is indecomposable, can I express it as the direct sum of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x)\bigoplus\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x)\bigoplus\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x)$ or can I not use the same simple sub-module more than once?

Comment: This is not unlike finding the subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}/p^3\Bbb{Z}$. Let $\pi:\Bbb{Q}[x]\to\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^3)$ be the natural projection. If $M$ is a submodule of $\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^3)$ then $\pi^{-1}(M)$ is a submodule of $\Bbb{Q}[x]$. That is, $\pi^{-1}(M)$ is a principal ideal that contains $x^3$. Therefore $\pi^{-1}(M)$ is generated by some factor of $x^3$. That quickly leads to the list of submodules in Ayaka's answer! Observe that the same argument works with any polynomial $f(x)$ in place of $x^3$. However, in the general case the factorization of $f(x)$ can be more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us denote $A=\mathbb{Q}[x]$, $M=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3)$ and let $N$ be an $A$-submodule. If $N\neq 0$, it has a nonzero element $f$. We denote the least degree term of $f$ by $ax^d\ (d\in \{0,1,2\},\ a\neq 0)$, so we can write
$$f=ax^d(1+xg)\ \ \ \ (g \text{ is a polynomial (chosen as a representative)}).$$
Let us pick up $A\ni h=1-xg+(xg)^2$. Since $N$ is closed under $A$-action, we have
$$h\cdot f=ax^d(1+x^3g^3)=ax^d\in N.$$
Therefore, $N$ contains either $1$, $x$ or $x^2$. Choosing the least possible such power, it follows that there are exactly four submodules $N$,
$$N=0,\ x^2A,\ xA, M.$$
They have different dimensions as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, so are different.

Besides, the indecomposability can be done independent of the classification of $N$. If $M$ is decomposed as $M\simeq N_1\oplus N_2$, then $\mathrm{End}(M)$ has at least two idempotents $(\mathrm{id}_{N_1},0)$ and $(0,\mathrm{id}_{N_2})$. But, in fact
$M$ is a cyclic (namely, generated by one element) module and $\mathrm{End}(M)$
has only one idempotent $\mathrm{id}_M$. So, it is indecomposable.

Comment: The correct set of submodules, so +1. I would skip using the idempotents. All the submodules form a nested chain
$$\langle 0\rangle\subset \langle x^2\rangle\subset \langle x\rangle\subset M.$$ And that alone excludes the possibility of direct sums appearing inside $M$.

Comment: Ah, that is much faster. Thank you :)